# Firebase - input array, output array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the most efficient way to input an array of keys to Firebase through iOS, of length >1000, and retrieve the corresponding elements in a dictionary? If the dictionary contains >1,000,000 entries then it is not optimal to make an unfiltered query and sort them locally. On the other hand, it also seems inefficient to make 1,000 individual network queries, although Firebase may be designed to handle this.

The third option I was considering is Firebase Cloud Functions, since it has the capacity to: "Execute intensive tasks in the cloud instead of in your app." Is this something that can be executed through Cloud Functions?

Here's an example of how the data is stored in Firebase:

[image]